# Affect of db availability during backups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-backups, database-administration

How can we know if you database is available while the backup jobs are running ? Do backups affect the availability of the databases ?

Please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Database backup does not obtain any locks or block anything while running.

Things that can cause some performance issue, If your are writing backups to the same drive where you data/data files are residing, if your system has to read and write at the same time on same drives than can slow the queries that are reading from database.

But I dont think anyone does backups to the same drives where data files are , kind of pointless. Other then that it shouldn't affect the performance.

Comment: What you are telling makes sense, our backups are not stored in same drive where data files are. But, how can we know if a database is available while the backup job for that database is running

Comment: It will be available to make sure you can run the backup job and at the same time execute USE database_name GO in SSMS, if it doesn't throw an error and changes the database, which it will it means your database is available to query.

Comment: I understand, but if suppose the backup job is running in the mid night. How can I know if my databases are available ?

Comment: Create another job that runs exactly the same time and you will see both jobs will be executed successfully.